# Can't get API - new httpModule Angular 5

Tags: angular, rest, httpclient

I try to display data from the iTunes API (https://itunes.apple.com) , but can't get the data.

First, I created an interface to get only the fields that I'm interested in:

```
export interface iTunesSearchResults {
artistName: string;
collectionName: string;
artworkUrl100: string;
}
```

This is my service:

```
albumListByArtist: iTunesSearchResults[];

getAlbums(): Observable<iTunesSearchResults[]> {
    return this._http.get<iTunesSearchResults[]>("https://itunes.apple.com/search?entity=album&term=Jay Z")

}
```

Then, this is the component:

```
albumListByArtist: iTunesSearchResults[];

getAlbums(): void {
    this.albumsList.getAlbums().subscribe(albums => { 
        this.albumListByArtist = albums;
        console.log(this.albumListByArtist);
        //console.log(this.albumListByArtist.collectionName);
    });

}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getAlbums();
}
```

Now, if for example I'll remove the // from `//console.log(this.albumListByArtist.collectionName);` , then I'll get an error

As well, I can't get the data at the template

Here's the console: 
[image]

So it's seems I get the data, but can't really access the fields I need.

I tried to map after the http.get.. .map(
but it didn't work

What I'm do wrong?

Thanks for helping

Comment: use this `this.albumListByArtist[0].collectionName`.  
It seems like it is an array

Comment: Still get error: "ERROR TypeError: Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: [object Error]: {description: "Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference", message: "Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference", ngDebugContext: Object, ngErrorLogger: function() { [native code] }, number: -2146823281...}

Comment: The thing is that for some reason I can't access the fields I need in the API

Comment: iTunes returns an object `{ resultCount: number, results: any[] }`.  You're trying to map it to an interface that only matches the results part.  Try mapping the response like `this._http.get("[itunes url]").map(data => data.results);`

Comment: Thanks!!! I had a feeling it's something with the return object the API, but couldn't figure out - thanks a lot!!! Works now.